# Отправка файлов на сервер Django через ajax

Tags: ajax, django, файлы

Здравствуйте, возникла проблема, что при отправке на сервер Django файлов через ajax ругается на:

> File "D:\WebSite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\http\multipartparser.py", line 72, in **init**
>       raise MultiPartParserError('Invalid boundary in multipart: %s' % boundary.decode())
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'
>   [25/Feb/2018 22:14:53] "POST /compare/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59`

Если в ajax в атрибуте contentType поставить false то выдаёт:

> File "D:\WebSite\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 79, in **getitem**
>       raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
>   django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'photo'

Если же отправлять картинку через форму в HTML то всё работает, вот код:

```html
<html>
<body>
 <video id="v" width="1024" height="950"></video>
 <input id="b" type="button" disabled="true" value="Take Picture">
 <canvas id="c" style="display:none;" width="1024" height="950"></canvas>
</body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
 navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, function(stream) {
  var video = document.getElementById("v");
  var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
  var button = document.getElementById("b");
  video.srcObject = stream;
  video.play();
  button.disabled = false;
  button.onclick = function() {
   canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(video, 0, 0, c.width, c.height, 0, 0, v.width, v.height);
   var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var fd = new FormData;
            fd.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '{{ csrf_token }}');
            fd.append('photo', $("#photo"));
   $.ajax({
                url: '/compare/',
                data: fd,
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
                contentType: "multipart/form-data",
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });

  };
 }, function(err) { alert("there was an error " + err)});
</script>
<form action="/compare/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
  <input id="photo" type="file" name="photo"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</html>
```

> views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    photo = request.FILES['photo']
    photo.name = blake2b(digest_size=12).hexdigest() + '.jpg'
    camera = Camera.objects.get(name='camera_1')
    os.remove(BASE_DIR + camera.photo.url)
    camera.photo = photo
    camera.save()
```